# Can not pull port along with ip addresses

Tags: powershell

I am learning and writing a script in regex to use it in PowerShell to automate add IP addresses and ports from csv file to txt file then use it to add rules in windows firewall to block this IP addresses.

This is my regex script `(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(\,\d+)`

This is my data

```
"2021-05-16 19:49:33","178.128.23.9","4125","online","2023-07-05","Dridex"
"2021-07-28 16:01:42","104.248.178.90","4664","offline","2023-06-05","Dridex"
"2021-08-27 04:48:12","192.99.150.39","7443","online","2023-07-05","Dridex"
```

The script find the IP addresses but that is it. I have spent a lot of time googling for a solution from multiply websites and watching videos on regex shorthand logic! What am I missing.

I have tried different script from regex community, some worked the same as my logic ip address only, and others did not. I have used Regex101 and Regexr and found out I like both interrupters thats it.

Comment: Why would you use regex for this instead of `Import-Csv` ?

Comment: You are missing to include the quotation marks in your RegEx. Though you should do as Santiago suggested, which is the more robust way to process CSV. If the CSV really has no headers, you can use the `-Header` parameter of `Import-Csv` to specify them manually.

Comment: Thank You. I have been torn between Import-Csv, Get-Child, and Get-Content.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no reason to do this with [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), you have a valid Csv already and PowerShell has built-in parsers to convert Csv into objects. If you want to ensure that what you have is a valid IP Address then you can use the [`IPAddress.TryParse` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse?view=net-7.0). If your Csv has no headers then you can include the headers you want using the [`-Header` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.3#-header).

As an example:

```bash
@'
"2021-05-16 19:49:33","178.128.23.9","4125","online","2023-07-05","Dridex"
"2021-07-28 16:01:42","104.248.178.90","4664","offline","2023-06-05","Dridex"
"2021-08-27 04:48:12","192.99.150.39","7443","online","2023-07-05","Dridex"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header date, ipaddress, port | ForEach-Object {
    # if this is a valid ipaddress
    if ([ipaddress]::TryParse($_.ipaddress, [ref] $null)) {
        # do stuff with `$_.ipaddress` and `$_.port`
        '{0}:{1}' -f $_.ipaddress, $_.port
    }
}
```

If you want to read the Csv from a source file you would be using `Import-Csv` instead:

```bash
# Note: `-Header` is only needed if the Csv has no headers.
Import-Csv path\to\csvfile.csv -Header date, ipaddress, port | ForEach-Object { ...
```

Comment: I have taken the approach to my problem and have extracted the ip and port from the CSV file and stored them in a text file.